# How can I capture the output of a child process spawned by a piped process?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdout

I want to continuously monitor a piped process and print its `stdout` and `stderr` as it comes in ( I'm not interested in getting the whole output all at once after it exited ). The problem is that the piped process spawns an other child process, and the `stdout` and `stderr` of that spawned process is not accessible using the pipes of the original process.

Namely I want to run a python program in this way, so the piped process is the python interpreter, but python interpreter spawns the running of the python program in an other subprocess, so I can't obtain the output of that ( the actual program output ). If there is an error starting the program, I can get this because this is printed to original python interpreter's `stderr`. But normal `stdout` from the actual program is lost for me.

I'm using `subprocess.Popen` .

Edit: A commenter asked for a code sample, I don't think this adds to much, but here is my code ( `PopenProcess` is an intelligent wrapper class for `subrpocess.Popen` but does nothing extraordinary ):

```
class BTask:
    def __init__(self, name, cmds, color = "NONE"):
        self.name = name
        self.cmds = cmds
        self.color = color
        self.proc = None

    def procreadline(self, sline):
        print(ANSI[self.color] + self.name + ANSI["ENDC"] + " > " + ANSI[self.color] + sline)

    def procreaderror(self, sline):
        print(ANSI[self.color] + self.name + ANSI["BRIGHTWHITE"] + " ! " + ANSI["BRIGHTRED"] + sline)

    def run(self):        
        print(ANSI["GREEN"])
        print("running task: {} {}".format(ANSI["BRIGHTGREEN"], self.name))
        pargs = []
        if len(self.cmds) > 1:
            pargs = self.cmds[1:]        
        print(ANSI[self.color])
        self.proc = PopenProcess(
            self.cmds[0],
            self.procreadline,
            read_error_callback = self.procreaderror,
            proc_args = pargs,
            ignore_cwd = True
            )

    def kill(self):
        print(ANSI["RED"])
        print("killing task: {} {}".format(ANSI["BRIGHTRED"], self.name))
        self.proc.kill()

    def is_alive():
        return self.proc.is_alive()
```

Comment: can you provide code sample?

Comment: @Serge , I provided my code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a piped process instead of

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'myprog.py'])
```

one should use

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u', 'myprog.py'])
```

Then it works.

The problem was with buffered output, and `-u` switch turns this off ( allows unbuffered output ).